como puedo previsualizar la url de una imagen y la imagen , antes de subirla a la base de datos
necesito ayuda, estoy creando un formulario para subir datos a la base de
datos y de momento todo bien almenos en lo que a php se refiere, me sube los datos a la base de datos y me escribe lo que le pido....
el problema lo tengo en javascript o jquery , en el que se mas bien poco. y es que necesito que al darle a un input type file o a un input type button o a un button html, me escriba la url en el input type url o text , para poder comprobar que el archivo se sube al directorio correcto y que al mismo tiempo me previsualize la imagen , para saber si subo esa u otra imagen y que si no subo ninguna , me muestre una imagen por defecto....
segun he leido es algo bastante sencillo para los que saben de javascript y jquery...
alguien podria ayudarme u orientarme...
<div class="img-perfil col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<a class="picture-perfil" data-track-action="NAVEGACION" data-track="ZOOM" href="../../Public/img/Imagen_Default.png" target="_blank">
   <picture>
      <img src="../../Public/img/Imagen_Default.png" alt="">
   </picture>
       <span class="zoom">
            <lable>Url Perfil</label>
                 <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" value="Examinar">
                 <input  name="url_thumbs" type="text" id="url_thumbs" size="38" value="" placeholder="../../Public/img/Imagen_Default.png">
       </span>
</a>


 tambien tengo un codigo php/javascript que use hace años para crear un formulario de registro , pero se trata de un select que te permite elegir una imagen(avatar) desde un directorio de la pagina o bien subir tu propia imagen del avatar al directorio de la pagina,y cuando le das a registro escribe todos los datos de registro en la base de datos , incluido la url de la imagen.... 
he intentado reutilizar este codigo, pero al no saber de javascript y/o Jquery, se me hace 
muy dificil ...
Subo codigo por si puede servir.....


Segunda vez, código en texto no en imagen. Además, te has planteado ver algún curso para aprender mejor estos temas, créeme hay ejemplos de todo y te explican como y para que es cada cosa. Ánimos!

intento subir codigo, pero no me deja.... segundo ya hice un curso , html5, css , php y javascript, pero hace mas de 15 años y hace mucho que no toco este mundillo , y no por falta de ganas, si no por falta de tiempo, el trabajo, mi mujer, el niño, problemas, y que quieres que te diga no he podido dedicerle el tiempo que necesita y me he quedado oxidado, por no decir obsoleto en este tema... nada me gustaria mas que encontrar , ha alguien que me explicara bien las cosas , me las refrescara y me enseñara mas, pero eso es dificil de encontrar...

y yo  no digo que lo que pregunto , no este explicado, solo que no lo encuentro.

Escribes tu pregunta literal en YouTube y ahí tienes como hacerlo. Todo lo que viste hace 15 años no existe! Debes renovar conocimientos, métodos y todas esas cosas. Yo, recomendaría esos cursos para al menos ir de nuevo actualizándote. Claro que deja, tienes código en tu pregunta, ¿Cómo explicas eso?

ya he conseguido previsualizar la imagen con js  he input type file, pero , queria hacerlo con un input type button o con un button html....por otro lado no consigo que me muestre la url de la imagen en el input type text que tiene al lado... agradeceria cualquier sugerencia....

solo me deja subir una linea de codigo, y si ya se que me tengo que actualizar , el problema es la falta de tiempo, aunque en algun momento tendre que empezar, solo que si empiezo y no lo termino, me quedo igual....

El código siempre como texto, con formato. Si en verdad es un [repro] (énfasis en mínimo), y el sitio lanza el error de que la pregunta es mayormente código, ponlo como texto sin formato, que luego con una edición se podrá corregir ese detalle.

Para mostrar el preview de una imagen, guardar el archivo y obtener la url donde se guardó puedes hacer lo siguiente:
Primero, en el input file se coloca una función al onchange (previewImagen) para que cuando se seleccione un archivo automáticamente se muestre el preview.
Segundo, a el form se le pasa una funcion onsubmit (guardarImagen) para manejar el proceso de guardado.
index.html
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="preview.js"></script>

<picture>
    <img src="../../Public/img/Imagen_Default.png" alt="" id="imagen_preview">
</picture>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="guardarImagen(event)">
    <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" value="Examinar" onchange="previewImagen(this)">
    <input name="url_thumbs" type="text" id="url_thumbs" size="38" value="" placeholder="../../Public/img/Imagen_Default.png">
    <button type="submit">Guardar imagen</button>
</form>

...
Luego con javascript definimos las funciones en prefiew.js; la función previewImagen hace un fecth a preview.php para obener la imagen previa de la url temporal de la imagen que se seleccionó en el input, la función guardarImagen hace fecth a preview.php para mover la imagen del input al servidor y recuperar la url donde se guardó
preview.js
...
const previewImagen = async (imagenFileInput) => {

   let formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append('traer_preview', true);
   formdata.append('imagen_icono', imagenFileInput.files[0]);

   let options = {
            method: "POST",
            body: formdata     
        };
   let p = await fetch("preview.php", options);
   let response = await p.json();

   document.getElementById('imagen_preview').setAttribute('src', response.imagen_temporal_preview);
}

const guardarImagen = async (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   let formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append('guardar_preview', true);
   formdata.append('imagen_icono', event.target.elements['archivo'].files[0]);

   let options = {
            method: "POST",
            body: formdata     
        };
   let p = await fetch("preview.php", options);
   let response = await p.json();
        
   alert('Imagen guardada, url actualizada en el input type="text"');
   document.getElementById('url_thumbs').setAttribute('value', response.result.url_icono);
}

...
Despues en preview.php importamos previewClass.php(código más abajo) que usaremos para leer o guardar el file, comprobamos en los array $_FILES y $_POST para determinar qué acción tomar (si "traer_preview" o "guardar_preview")
preview.php
...
<?php 
require_once 'previewClass.php';

if(isset($_FILES['imagen_icono'])){

   if(isset($_POST['traer_preview'])) {
    
    $imagenIcono = $_FILES['imagen_icono'];
    $previewClassInstancia =  new Preview($imagenIcono);
    echo json_encode(["imagen_temporal_preview" => $previewClassInstancia->getPreviewUrlTemporal()]);
   }

   if(isset($_POST['guardar_preview'])) {

    $imagenIcono = $_FILES['imagen_icono'];
    $previewClassInstancia =  new Preview($imagenIcono);
    echo json_encode(["result" => $previewClassInstancia->guardarImagenIconoPreview()]);
   }
}

Por último el código de la clase previewClass.php, que igual tiene 2 métodos, getPreviewUrlTemporal() que utiliza el tmp_name para cargar el archivo temporal y te regresa una imagen en base64, y guardarImagenIconoPreview() donde se crea un nuevo nombre para la imgagen, se determina su ubicación, se pone en el server y te regresa un arreglo con la url donde se subió el nuevo archivo
...
class Preview {

public $preview;
private $imagenFile;

public function __construct($file) {
    $this->imagenFile = $file;
}

public function getPreviewUrlTemporal(){

    $tipo = pathinfo($this->imagenFile['tmp_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $imagen = file_get_contents($this->imagenFile['tmp_name']);
    $imagenBase64 = 'data:image/' . $tipo . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imagen);
    return $imagenBase64;
}

public function guardarImagenIconoPreview(){
        $carpeta = "img/icons/avatar/";
        $nombreImagenIcono = 'icono_'.date("Ymdhis").'_'.basename($this->imagenFile["name"]);
        $fileCrear = $carpeta . $nombreImagenIcono;
        if (move_uploaded_file($this->imagenFile['tmp_name'], $fileCrear)) {
            return array(
                "subida_mensaje" => "El icono ". $nombreImagenIcono . " se ha subido con éxito.",
                "subida_estatus" => "ok",
                "url_icono" => $fileCrear 
            );
        }
}
}

